# python pandas. Sum of a column based on a match of string column in a comma separated values of another column

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, pandas-groupby

I have 2 data frames sample, with names changed:

`df1` =

| Comp_code | DepartmentListA | DepartmentListB |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Code_1 | "Dept1" | "Dept3" |
| Code_2 | "Dept2" | "Dept4" |
| Code_3 | "Dept4, Dept5" | "Dept1" |
| Code_4 | "Dept1,Dept5, Dept6" | "Dept3, Dept4" |

`df2` = with just department and revenue

| DepartmentList | Revenue | Gross Margin |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "Dept1" | 1000 | 500 |
| "Dept2" | 2000 | 0 |
| "Dept3, | 5000 | 900 |
| "Dept4" | 5000 | 200 |
| "Dept5" | 7000 | -100 |
| "Dept6" | 8000 | 2500 |

**I would like my final df to have company codes and total revenue and gross margin. Summing up totals of departments in column A and B.**
I am not able to iterate and join because of the comma separated string of departments. My final DF should be something like this

expected df =

| Comp_code | GrossRev | Tot Margin |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Code_1 | 6000 | 1400 |
| Code_2 | 7000 | 200 |
| Code_3 | 13000 | 600 |
| Code_4 | 26000 | 4000 |

Also the data frames are both a couple of million rows and some department lists (comma separated values) are about 100 in number. Would be good if there was a performant way of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works. It's very long, but it's mostly just repetitive.

```
new_df = df1[['Comp_code']].copy()
new_df['GrossRev'] = df1['DepartmentListB'].str.split(',').explode().map(df2.set_index('DepartmentList')['Revenue']).groupby(level=0).sum() + df1['DepartmentListA'].str.split(',').explode().map(df2.set_index('DepartmentList')['Revenue']).groupby(level=0).sum()
new_df['Tot Margin'] = df1['DepartmentListB'].str.split(',').explode().map(df2.set_index('DepartmentList')['GrossMargin']).groupby(level=0).sum() + df1['DepartmentListA'].str.split(',').explode().map(df2.set_index('DepartmentList')['GrossMargin']).groupby(level=0).sum()
```

Output:

```
>>> new_df
  Comp_code  GrossRev  Tot Margin
0    Code_1      6000        1400
1    Code_2      7000         200
2    Code_3     13000         600
3    Code_4     26000        4000
```

Comment: TY! I'm on python 2.7 and pandas 0.24. Explode does not work? Would you have any alternatives for older versions?

Comment: Ah yes, `explode` was added in 0.25! But I'll see if I can come up with something ;)